# Unable to get event listeners for hidden input field to work

Tags: addeventlistener

I'm trying to get this code to work on an input form to enable and disable on an "Add to Cart" button. The button is disabled intially and when I select the radio buttons it enables the button but the event listeners for the hidden fields (hiddenInput3, hiddenInput4, hiddenInput6, hiddenInput7) do not seem to work even though the value of the input is changing from 0 to 1.

I would appreciate any input that could steer me in the right direction.
Thank you

```
// Function to enable/disable the button and update its text
    function updateAddToCartButton() {
        var addToCartButton = document.getElementById("indiv_prod_button");
        var hiddenInput3 = document.getElementById("prod3_indiv_qty");
        var hiddenInput4 = document.getElementById("prod4_indiv_qty");
        var hiddenInput6 = document.getElementById("prod6_indiv_qty");
        var hiddenInput7 = document.getElementById("prod7_indiv_qty");
        var vetChoice = document.querySelectorAll("#vet_choice input[type=radio]");
        var vetChoiceSelected = Array.from(vetChoice).some(function (radio) {
            return radio.checked;
        });
        if (vetChoiceSelected || hiddenInput3.value === "1" || hiddenInput4.value === "1" || hiddenInput6.value === "1" || hiddenInput7.value === "1") {
            addToCartButton.textContent = "Add to Cart";
        } else {
            addToCartButton.textContent = "Select a Membership";
        }
        addToCartButton.disabled = !vetChoiceSelected && hiddenInput3.value !== "1" && hiddenInput4.value !== "1" && hiddenInput6.value !== "1" && hiddenInput7.value !== "1";
    }
    // Attach the update function to input elements change event
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("#vet_choice input[type=radio]");
    inputs.forEach(function(input) {
        input.addEventListener("change", updateAddToCartButton);
    });
    // Attach event listeners to hidden inputs
    var hiddenInput3 = document.getElementById("prod3_indiv_qty");
    var hiddenInput4 = document.getElementById("prod4_indiv_qty");
    var hiddenInput6 = document.getElementById("prod6_indiv_qty");
    var hiddenInput7 = document.getElementById("prod7_indiv_qty");
    hiddenInput3.addEventListener('change', updateAddToCartButton);
    hiddenInput4.addEventListener('change', updateAddToCartButton);
    hiddenInput6.addEventListener('change', updateAddToCartButton);
    hiddenInput7.addEventListener('change', updateAddToCartButton);
    // Initial call to set the button text
    updateAddToCartButton();
```